# How to merge (append) two tables in ArcGIS 9.3.1?

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-9.3

How do I merge 2 tables (they both have the same field names and columns) in ArcGIS 9.3.1 ?

Comment: please clarify. If you have key values you can do a join or relate. this only temporarily "merges the tables. any like column names will be treated (temp) as mytable1.myfield and mytable2.myfield. you can create a permanent version. If that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Going off @Brad Nesom, if you export the file with the joins, it creates a new shapefile including the joined data but without the disadvantages of a join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Merge tool

Data Managment Tools > General > Merge

Comment: This one is good to do the merge easily.

Answer (score 2):

Or get the python window open and:

```
gp.merge_management(fc1, fc2)
```

or

```
gp.Append_management(fc1, fc2,"NO_TEST")
```

Where fc1 can be a list of featureclasses merged into fc2.  There are many ways to do this, but this for me would be the easiest as all you have to do is typre the first part, then drag in the names from the fc's from the TOC.  Very easy.